# React + Socket IO: Accessing the first message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to create an auto reply after a user has sent his first message. I have no problems with the reply, it's just knowing when the a user has sent his first message (and first message only).

I have an USER prop that contains users id.

here is my hook that is responsible for the message sending

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on("msg", msg=> {
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.MSG,
          value: msg
        });
      });
```

in the reducer the messages is an array. So I've been thinking of just creating something like

```
   PSEUDO CODE if (the user PROP.Type === 'userType1' && sends.message[0]) {
    return autoReply
    }
```

Comment: If I understand you well, why not emit an auto-reply from the server when the user sends a message and in the client listening to it?

Comment: I should've used a better example. I have couple of things I want to do on the Front Side when a user of prop.type === 'userType1' sends his first message. One of them is an API call.